# What kind of metaphor is "trees in the wind"?

Tags: metaphor, figures-of-speech

What kind of metaphor is "trees in the wind"?

> I saw God in the Forest
>
> Teachin' Tai Chi
>
> **To the trees in the wind**
>
> Bowing to the sea

Excerpt from http://www.bensollee.com/panning-for-gold

What I find odd is that the reference is "trees in the wind" and not just a word and the referee is not obvious, because it doesn't seem to be comparing it to anything and the intended can be just "trees moving with the wind" instead of "tree in the wind" as if the trees are flying in the wind. What's the intended effect and what kind of metaphor is this if it indeed is a metaphor? I am talking about "trees in the wind" specifically and not "teachin' Tai Chi to the trees in the wind".

Comment: I've added to my answer, after your edit.

Comment: Actually "Trees in the wind" is the only phrase that is not a metaphor in this poem. It's literally trees swaying in the wind.

Comment: Hi Blackbird.  This is not really a writing question as currently posed.  It should probably be better asked on Literature SE instead (questions about existing literary works are not on topic here).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### It's [Personification](https://literarydevices.net/personification/).

While it is a type of metaphor, this is called **personification**. The intent here is simply to describe the random movement of the tree branches with a sense of purpose. Although "God" is mentioned as the teacher, the poem is not describing something holy or religious, rather the slow, intentional martial arts motions of Tai Chi.

From the link:

> Personification is not merely a decorative device, but serves the
>   purpose of giving deeper meanings to literary texts. It adds vividness
>   to expressions, as we always look at the world from a human
>   perspective. Writers and poets rely on personification to bring
>   inanimate things to life, so that their nature and actions are
>   understood in a better way. Because it is easier for us to relate to
>   something that is human, or which possesses human traits...

"Trees in the wind" *specifically* is not a metaphor, it's just *a figure of speech* or an **idiom**.

Comment: Does "in the wind" mean it's flying or it's wavering under the influence of the wind?

Comment: @blackbird, it's skipping an implied verb: "trees (blowing, bending, waving) in the wind…", like "a woman in leather" skips a verb "wearing", and "frog in a blender" skips a verb "spinning" – there is an action or activity that is implied. The idiom that would mean the trees are *flying* would probably be **"trees (up) in the air..."** or "trees in the sky".

Comment: Ah, ok, makes sense now.

Answer (score 3):

More explicitly stated, the metaphor is that the trees move to and fro in the wind because God (using the wind) is teaching them Tai Chi.

The imagery is the trees of the forest moving in unison like we see a group of people in the park move in unison when being led in a Tai Chi class. God is the instructor leading the trees.

Answer (score 0):

Actually you need to look at that phrase in the context of the whole poem. From God's repeated statement that He has forgotten where he put things it becomes clear that God has lost His people and forgotten who they are. Instead of to men, He is speaking to nature.

So the trees aren't a metaphor, but in fact they are just trees. They bow to the sea in the same way that men used to bow to God, but the trees just bow before the wind, without any meaning or intent.

Comment: You've posted a lot of answers, I'd recommend signing up for a full account to make it easier to track your reputation and badges. Currently, you're at risk of losing access to your account the next time you visit, and ending up with a new one.

Comment: @F1Krazy I'm not really interested in reputation. I'm just here for a few minutes because I'm bored. I'm leaving already.

Comment: Awww. That is a shame. I do hope you change your mind!